# Create a Mvc2 Project with Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I've read how to use Spark View Engine instead of Webform View Engine in a Mvc2 Project so I think we can do the same with Razor View Engine but when I search on GOOGLE, I cant find anything helpful. So, to you pros I post this question. Please help! Thanks so much!


**Attention: Razor in Mvc2 project, not in Mvc3.**
Thanks again!

Comment: Try to elaborate your question.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While this is technically possible, you'll need to copy vast swaths of code from the MVC3 source.

Razor will still need .Net 4.0, so this is really not worth it; you should just upgrade to MVC3.