# Razor engine on MVC 1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there anyway to make razor engine works on MVC 1?

I have to use MVC 1 because I'm working on Visual studio 2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Mvc2 Project with Razor View Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274066/create-a-mvc2-project-with-razor-view-engine)

Comment: dude, get VS2010 and start working on MVC3! you are wasting your time on MVC 1:S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Razor requires .NET 4.0 and works only with ASP.NET MVC 3, which is not supported in Visual Studio 2008. So the answer is no.

Comment: razor is introduced with ASP.NET MVC3 but it doesn't require .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to backport the Razor ViewEngine to MVC1, although you'll lose a lot of features.

However, it won't help; Razor itself *requires* .Net 4.0, which is not available on VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. The razor view engine is only supported in ASP.NET MVC 3.