# Does cshtml files exist in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I am learning ASP.NET MVC currently, and looking at the concept of Display and Editor Templates. I am working through a post by Scott Mitchell about [Using Templates to Display Boolean Values as Yes/No Options](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/11/22/using-templates-to-display-boolean-values-as-yes-no-options.aspx).  In it Scott uses .cshtml files within the Shared Folder to store reusable interface templates.

I can't find any way to create .cshtml files in Visual Studio 2008 / ASP.NET MVC 2.  Are they an ASP.NET MVC 3 only thing?  Would there be a way to build custom templates without upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cshtml` files are razor views. The Razor view engine is part of Asp.NET MVC 3 (Visual Studio 2010 only), yes.

More Information: [Introducing “Razor” – a new view engine for ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

Similar SO Post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274066/create-a-mvc2-project-with-razor-view-engine)
Here is a [blog post](http://stefan.rusek.org/Posts/Using-Razor-with-ASP-NET-MVC-in-Four-Easy-Steps/26/) that may help you get Razor working with MVC 2. Note this is from 2010.
There are at least a couple of third party view engines including NHAML and SparkView. I believe that these should work with MVC 2. 
Here are a coiple of links: [comparison of view engines](http://ironshay.com/post/The-Big-View-Engine-Comparison-e28093-Razor-vs-Spark-vs-NHaml-vs-Web-Forms-View-Engine.aspx), [NHAML](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-35-use-the-nhaml-view-engine.aspx) at Stephen Walther site

Answer (score 0):

After some research, and reading some of the links from @dknaack and @ashok, I have figured out that I can still create custom templates in MVC 2 using MVC 2 View User Controls, which are .ascx files.  A comparable .ascx file to the .cshtml in Scott's blog would look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<% if(ViewData.Model is bool && ((bool)ViewData.Model) == true)
   { %>
   <div>Yes</div>
<%}else{ %>
   <div>No</div>
<%} %>
```